# Pandas dataframe indexing by date

Tags: python, pandas, time-series

So Python, with the pandas module seems like a great option to matlab and R. This is why I've very recently switched to this. There are resources out there, and I've searched the forum but couldn't find anything similar. If you have links to some tutorials or other useful material out there, please post them.

Wes McKinney has a great and elaborate tutorial on pandas.
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w26x-z-BdWQ&list=FLJ5xKwlfj7wg8S_A5SgR6Wg&feature=mh_lolz

At 1:10 he shows an example of how to index the rows in a dataframe by dates rather than integers.
I would like to do something similar.

The difference is that I have 3 variables, Y1, Y2, Y3, each with a column of timestamps, X1, X2, X3.

```
TestFile.txt:  
X1  Y1  X2  Y2  X3  Y3
27/11/2012  11.436  29/11/2012  20.631  4/12/2012   10.209  
28/11/2012  11.468  30/11/2012  20.185  5/12/2012   9.973  
29/11/2012  11.414  3/12/2012   19.962  6/12/2012   9.736  
30/11/2012  11.355  4/12/2012   19.562  7/12/2012   9.509  
3/12/2012   11.309  5/12/2012   18.908  10/12/2012  9.259  
4/12/2012   11.118  6/12/2012   18.288  11/12/2012  8.109  
5/12/2012   10.873  7/12/2012   17.973  
6/12/2012   10.582  10/12/2012  17.788  
7/12/2012   10.264  11/12/2012  17.554  
10/12/2012  9.886  
11/12/2012  9.164
```

Where I want to do 4 things:

1. Associate data in Yi by its date in Xi for i = 1,2,3
2. Index rows by dates
3. Remove all data that is older than 4/12/2012 which is the first date of Y3
4. Be able to access all date by date and column only

Here is a test file which describes how the data is read and how it prints.
You can see that X1 is correctly parsed to the pandas date format, but not X2 or X3. which is what I attempted to do by specifying
index_col=[0,2,4]
and
parse_dates = True

```
TestFile.py:
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('TestFile.txt',sep='\t', index_col=[0,2,4], parse_dates = True)

print 'pandas version: ', pd.__version__
print df
```

Gives output:

```
pandas version:  0.10.0b1
X1         X2         X3              Y1      Y2      Y3                   
2012-11-27 29/11/2012 4/12/2012   11.436  20.631  10.209
2012-11-28 30/11/2012 5/12/2012   11.468  20.185   9.973
2012-11-29 3/12/2012  6/12/2012   11.414  19.962   9.736
2012-11-30 4/12/2012  7/12/2012   11.355  19.562   9.509
2012-03-12 5/12/2012  10/12/2012  11.309  18.908   9.259
2012-04-12 6/12/2012  11/12/2012  11.118  18.288   8.109
2012-05-12 7/12/2012  None        10.873  17.973     NaN
2012-06-12 10/12/2012 None        10.582  17.788     NaN
2012-07-12 11/12/2012 None        10.264  17.554     NaN
2012-10-12 None       None         9.886     NaN     NaN
2012-11-12 None       None         9.164     NaN     NaN
```

Wanted output:

```
                Y1      Y2       Y3                 
2012-04-12  11.118  19.562   10.209
2012-05-12  10.873  18.908    9.973
2012-06-12  10.582  18.288    9.736
2012-07-12  10.264  17.973    9.509
2012-10-12   9.886  17.788    9.259
2012-11-12   9.164  17.554    8.109
```

If you have any idea of how to do this, your help is much appreciated:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your confusion is due to a misunderstanding about the `index_col` argument. When you pass a list of columns to `index_col`, pandas is attempting to create a multi-index, that is, a dataframe with more than one column as index, like a multi-dimensional table. It is NOT trying to create a single index by concatenating multiple columns.

One strategy that would work is to create three dataframes with the appropriate pairs of columns from your input file, and then concatenate them.

X1  Y1  X2  Y2  X3  Y3 --> Dataframe of (X1, Y1) + Dataframe of (X2, Y2) + Dataframe of (X3, Y3)

If you are using the latest development version of Pandas, or are willing to, this is simplified by using the new `parse_cols` argument in `read_csv()`. Or you can read in all the data, extract the three dataframes you need, and then concatenate them.

Finally, you can `df.truncate` with `before` and `after` arguments to get the DateRange you need. More simply, you could use `dropna()` to omit dates with missing values.

Hope this helps. Do let us know what version of pandas you are using.

Comment: So this works:  
df1 = pd.read_csv('TestFile.txt',sep='\t', index_col = 0,parse_dates = True, usecols = [0,1])

And this pulls out the right dates for the second series, but doesnt parse the dates:

df2 = pd.read_csv('TestFile.txt',sep='\t', index_col = 0,parse_dates = True, usecols = [2,3])

Comment: If you're having trouble parsing the dates in the same step as `read_csv()` then don't worry -- just read the dates in as strings. After you've concatenated the data into one df, _then_ create the datetime index from the column containing the date strings.

Answer (score 2):

by setting `index_col=[0,2,4]` you are creating a MultiIndex that's why you get that output.

For the output you want read_csv will not be able to do this on the fly. Just read single and merge the dataframes